# GWT code-splitting download progressbar - like gmail

Tags: gwt, download, progress-bar

I have to use code-splitting in my project. but anyway there are some codes for initial downloading for first time.

Now I want to show to end-user the progress for code downloading (.cache.html - or other code-splitting) like gmail startup progress.

Would you please help me.

RGDS

Answer (score 5):

According to the [design](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html#sequence) (roughly), it mentions splitting off modules where it makes sense since it doesn't technically support pre-fetching; that being said, I can only assume GMail is showing progress based on the module loading progress checked via callbacks (i.e `GWT.runAsync()`). Not all modules are the same size, but you could "guesstimate" and assign a weighted percentage for each module (See GWT's [compile report](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompileReport.html))

1. If your initial page size download is large(>= 1 MB), I would recommend looking into refactoring and optimizing your design to be a little more lightweight (scaffolding). Which would mean more trips to the server but limit the initial download size. That would provide the basis to plumb some more precise feedback to the user that the page is  "working" (i.e. *indeterminate progress bar*) and avoid unnecessary precision.
2. Total page size is a difficult thing to really measure en-route to the client/browser, it would be more trouble than it's worth to display this to the user. You *could* probably accomplish this with several lightweight modules but you'll have to compensate for all the generated resources like `ClientBundle` because GWT creates a specific set for each browser permutation.

**Sidenote**: 
Real time feedback such as for file size precision progress (e.g. 80 KB of 1.29MB (6% Complete)) is typically used when downloading a file (e.g. images, video, music, et al) to the user's hard drive. The data at that point is no longer transient and storage space may be a concern, caches clear out and flush so it's generally not a big deal how big a web page is.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this and please comment if it works or not;

I'll only send html file to you. You could design according to your code. 
How this is woking. There is a div element including "loading". When the page lads first simple html loaded and loading text will be displayed. After html file loaded your nocache.js file will start(still your seeing loaidng text). After js file loaded onmoduleload script will start(still text loading seen) and after the all widgets created and your panels etc ready. Try below code and remove "loading" text from screen;

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.Element loading = DOM.getElementById("loading");
DOM.removeChild(RootPanel.getBodyElement(), loading);
```

proje.html;

```
 <!doctype html>
<!-- The DOCTYPE declaration above will set the    -->
<!-- browser's rendering engine into               -->
<!-- "Standards Mode". Replacing this declaration  -->
<!-- with a "Quirks Mode" doctype may lead to some -->
<!-- differences in layout.                        -->

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <!--                                                               -->
    <!-- Consider inlining CSS to reduce the number of requested files -->
    <!--                                                               -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<proje>.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/gxt-all.css" />

    <!--                                           -->
    <!-- Any title is fine                         -->
    <!--                                           -->
    <title><Proje></title>

    <!--                                           -->
    <!-- This script loads your compiled module.   -->
    <!-- If you add any GWT meta tags, they must   -->
    <!-- be added before this line.                -->
    <!--                                           -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<proje>/<proje>.nocache.js"></script>
  </head>

  <!--                                           -->
  <!-- The body can have arbitrary html, or      -->
  <!-- you can leave the body empty if you want  -->
  <!-- to create a completely dynamic UI.        -->
  <!--                                           -->
  <body>

    <!-- OPTIONAL: include this if you want history support -->
    <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>

    <!-- RECOMMENDED if your web app will not function without JavaScript enabled -->
    <noscript>
      <div style="width: 22em; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -11em; color: red; background-color: white; border: 1px solid red; padding: 4px; font-family: sans-serif">

      </div>
    </noscript>

    <div align="center" id="loading"> 
        <table style="height:600px;" border="0">
            <tr height="100%">
                <td align="center">
                    <b>Loading...</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="main" style="display:none">
       <table border="0" width="100%" height="100%" align="center" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" width="100%" id="ustMenuPanel"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr height="100%" valign="top">
                <td id="menuPanel" width="20%"></td>
                <td id="modulPanel" width="80%"></td>
              </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The "problem" with that is, that the user doesn't know how much has been loaded. Do you have a idea, how I could get something like "100kb from 500kb loaded"?

Comment: @Chris_Boesing Yes you are right, I only try to give a sample to starting point of your question.

Comment: yes guys, it works but as Chris said I want to know how percentage is completed

Answer (score 0):

GWT doesn't have any widget like **progress bar**. I also wanted to add this feature to my application but I couldn't

You can use incubator progress bar.

http://google-web-toolkit-incubator.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo/ProgressBar/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This question isn't about a progressbar in your app, it is about a progressbar that is shown before the app is completely loaded, so the user knows how long he has to wait.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your comment. I just want to show the progressbar and its usage

Answer (score 0):

You could take the same approach as [Apache Hupa](http://james.apache.org/hupa/index.html), which just shows an animated gif while the application is loading. Once the application has loaded, it removes the animated gif through the dom structure of the hostpage.